# How do you limit the blur in a linear gradient on a canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, chart.js

I am trying to create a color gradient like the one in the image below.

However my gradient is very blurred and the colors are not separated nicely like in the image.

Is it possible to create something like this? I have created a JSFiddle where I use the createLinearGradient method on a canvas chart.

Here is the JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uo8z2tub/1/

Here is the code for creating the gradient in my JSFiddle:

```
// Create gradient
    grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 400.000, 0, 100.000);

// Add colors
    grd.addColorStop(0.000, 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1.000)');
    grd.addColorStop(0.200, 'rgba(191, 255, 0, 1.000)');
    grd.addColorStop(0.400, 'rgba(221, 255, 0, 1.000)');
    grd.addColorStop(0.600, 'rgba(255, 229, 0, 1.000)');
    grd.addColorStop(0.800, 'rgba(255, 144, 0, 1.000)');
    grd.addColorStop(1.000, 'rgba(255, 50, 0, 1.000)');
```

[image]

Comment: you need to set start and stop for each colors https://jsfiddle.net/uo8z2tub/2/

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the colorStops really close to each other like so :

```
grd.addColorStop(0.000, 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1.000)');
   grd.addColorStop(0.199, 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1.000)');
grd.addColorStop(0.200, 'rgba(191, 255, 0, 1.000)');
 grd.addColorStop(0.399, 'rgba(191, 255, 0, 1.000)');
grd.addColorStop(0.400, 'rgba(221, 255, 0, 1.000)');
 grd.addColorStop(0.599, 'rgba(221, 255, 0, 1.000)');
grd.addColorStop(0.600, 'rgba(255, 229, 0, 1.000)');
 grd.addColorStop(0.799, 'rgba(255, 229, 0, 1.000)');
grd.addColorStop(0.800, 'rgba(255, 144, 0, 1.000)');
grd.addColorStop(0.999, 'rgba(255, 144, 0, 1.000)');
grd.addColorStop(1.000, 'rgba(255, 50, 0, 1.000)');
```